# Fill in blank Excel cells using value from another column value but not in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I have blank cells in column G and H (the blank cells will always be in the same row as each other) that I would like to fill with cell values from non-contiguous columns, K and L (data always starts in `K13` and `L13`).

For the columns, I know that the range would start on row 13, but the last row of the data varies.
For columns K and L, column K data needs to go to column G and column L needs to go to column H.

If for example, I had data in `K13:l14`, and an empty row of data in `G20:H20` and `G24:H24`, is there a way I can copy the data in `K13:L14` over to the empty cells WITHOUT KNOWING where the empty row of data starts?

[image: Need to move the red values over to the blank spaces]

Comment: Is the data you would like to use to fill the gaps in K:L or L:M. Your question and picture to not match.

Comment: Oh sorry, Ben! IT was K:L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub fillGaps()
    Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
    Set wrkSheet = ActiveSheet 'Change to Sheets("[name]")
    
    Dim fillerRange As Range
    Set fillerRange = wrkSheet.Range("L13:M13") 'This is the first cell with filler data
    
    Dim gapRange As Range
    Set gapRange = wrkSheet.Range("G13:H13") 'This is the first cell to check if blank

    While hasData(fillerRange) 'Keep going until no more filler data
        While hasData(gapRange) 'Keep going until there is a blank
            Set gapRange = gapRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Wend
        Set fillerRange = fillerRange.Offset(1, 0)
        fillerRange.Offset(-1, 0).Copy gapRange
        fillerRange.Offset(-1, 0).Clear
    Wend
    
End Sub

Function hasData(r) As Boolean
    'This function determines if there are any non-blank cells in a range.
    'Note, if the range will not have formulas you can simply use CountA instead.
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            hasData = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
    hasData = False
End Function
```

Note: This only works if the active sheet is the one with the gapped data. See my comment on how to fix this.

**Modified code to match specifications in comments below**

Sub fillGaps()
Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
Set wrkSheet = ActiveSheet 'Change to Sheets("[name]")

```
Dim fillerRange As Range
Set fillerRange = wrkSheet.Range("K13", wrkSheet.Range("L13").End(xlDown).Address)

Dim gapRange As Range
Set gapRange = wrkSheet.Range("G13:H13")
While hasData(fillerRange)
    While hasData(gapRange)
        Set gapRange = gapRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
    fillerRange.Cut fillerRange.Offset(gapRange.Row - fillerRange.Row, 0)
    Set fillerRange = fillerRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Set gapRange = gapRange.Offset(1, 0)
Wend
```

End Sub

Function hasData(r) As Boolean
For Each cell In r
If cell.Value <> "" Then
hasData = True
Exit Function
End If
Next cell
hasData = False
End Function

Comment: Actually i realized i messed up with my picture even more...i need to move values K:L down its column to the empty rows. So if there's empty cells in row 20, i'd need to move values in K:L down to K20:L20...

Comment: So you don't want to fill in the gaps but rather move the data in K:L to the same row as the gaps?

Comment: Also, please try to be careful when asking questions as confusions slow me down and prevent me from being able to help others.

Comment: Really apologize about that, Ben...I will be more careful when posing my questions. That's correct though, i want to move the data down. so i was able to do so by offsetting where i pasted my values. Appreciate you taking your time to review my question.

Comment: Great! If you believe I answered the question, please mark it so others can know the problem is solved. If not, please let me know what doesn't work